# python insert data into sqlite 3 from an interface

Tags: python, tkinter

So i was designing a terminal based application in  python 3, I finshed designing  the GUI for the app. and I designed a database in sqlite3  now my problem is I have to insert data from GUI when i hit the submit button into the database. Basically I have front end and back end what remaining is the connection.

```
# import Statements
# Used Api Library "ttt"
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

# class is made 
class MovieOrganizer:

    #init method
    def __init__(self, master):    


        # <----- Header Coding starts here -------> 
        self.frame_header = ttk.Frame(master)
        self.frame_header.pack()

        #Importing the picture
        self.logo = PhotoImage(file = 'movie_logo.png')

        # creating the labels in the frame header. 
        ttk.Label(self.frame_header, image = self.logo).grid(row = 0, column = 0, rowspan = 2)
        ttk.Label(self.frame_header, text = 'Welcome to movie organizer!').grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        ttk.Label(self.frame_header, wraplength = 300,
                  text = ("By the application you easily know different category  of movies you want to watch and when to watch.  "
                          "You can also categorize the movies, save the date you watched and find the location of the movie in your systm.")).grid(row = 1, column = 1)



        # <----- Content Coding starts here -------> 
        self.frame_content = ttk.Frame(master)
        self.frame_content.pack()

        # creating the labels in the frame content.

        ttk.Label(self.frame_content, text = 'Movie Name:').grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 5, sticky = 'sw')
        ttk.Label(self.frame_content, text = 'Movie category:').grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 5, sticky = 'sw')
        ttk.Label(self.frame_content, text = 'Date you watched:').grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 5, sticky = 'sw')
        ttk.Label(self.frame_content, text = 'Rate the movie out of 10:').grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 5, sticky = 'sw')
        ttk.Label(self.frame_content, text = 'Any Comments on the movie?:').grid(row = 4, column = 0, padx = 5, sticky = 'sw')
        # I need to add more label later on. 


        #input fields for the label created
        #varible is assigned 
        self.entry_name = ttk.Entry(self.frame_content, width = 24)
        self.entry_category = ttk.Entry(self.frame_content, width = 24)
        self.entry_category = ttk.Entry(self.frame_content, width = 24)
        self.entry_date = ttk.Entry(self.frame_content, width = 24)
        self.entry_rate = ttk.Entry(self.frame_content, width = 24)
        #self.check() 
        self.text_comments = Text(self.frame_content, width = 50, height = 10)


        #position setting for the inputs 
        self.entry_name.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 5)
        self.entry_category.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 5)
        self.entry_date.grid(row = 3, column = 0, padx = 5)
        self.entry_rate.grid(row = 3, column = 1, padx = 5)
        self.text_comments.grid(row = 5, column = 0, columnspan = 2, padx = 5)


        #setting the buttons submit button submit form to db and clear clears all the values for a reentery
        # I need to add 2 more button but db connectivity should be there.  One button is a view button I will put a view for all the movies.  And second button is delete the entry 
        ttk.Button(self.frame_content, text = 'Submit', command = self.submit).grid(row = 6, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = 'e')
        ttk.Button(self.frame_content, text = 'Clear', command = self.clear).grid(row = 6, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = 'w')
        #ttk.Button(self.frame_content, text = '', command = self.view).grid(row = 6, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5, sticky = 'e')



        # an if coditon Want to fix it before next prototype. 
       # def check(self):
        #    if self.entry_rate <10:
         #        messagebox.showinfo(title = 'New Movie Entry ', message = 'Updated!')


         # this method works on submit button    


    def submit(self):
        print('Name: {}'.format(self.entry_name.get()))
        print('Category: {}'.format(self.entry_category.get()))
        print('Date: {}'.format(self.entry_date.get()))
        print('Rate: {}'.format(self.entry_rate.get()))

        print('Comments: {}'.format(self.text_comments.get(1.0, 'end')))
        self.clear()

        messagebox.showinfo(title = 'New Movie Entry ', message = 'Updated!')



    def clear(self):
        self.entry_name.delete(0, 'end')
        self.entry_category.delete(0, 'end')
        self.entry_date.delete(0, 'end')
        self.entry_rate.delete(0, 'end')
        self.text_comments.delete(1.0, 'end')
   # def view(self):

def main():            

    root = Tk()
    movieOrganizer = MovieOrganizer(root)
    root.mainloop()

    #if conditiom 
if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Comment: Sorry for got add code for my database                                                              >>> con sqlite3.connect ('hrdb')
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> con = sqlite3.connect ('hrdb')
>>> type (con)
<class 'sqlite3.Connection'>
>>> cur = con.cursor()
>>> cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE moview (id integer primary key, Movie varchar(50), category vatchar(50), date varchar(50), rate integer, comments varchar(50))''')

<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x02A558E0>

<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x02A558E0>

Comment: What is your question? What part of the problem are you having difficulties with?

Comment: I need to enter data from my interface when i click the submit button. I have made the interface and db but I cant enter data from interface into database

Comment: What does "can't" mean? Are you getting errors? If so, what errors?

Answer (score 0):

i am kind of new but looking at your code you do not got any of the connections for sqlite in the snippets on the same page if you got it you could repair that broken code and attach every line to it , so at the end you got the db and the code running ...

Comment: I'd just like to point out this post has been inactive for almost 2 years with no response to the comment above. Best of luck getting a reply and Welcome to StackOverflow!